# How does the wallet prioritise keypool addresses imported via importmulti?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I want to use `importmulti` to import 100 addresses from an xpub descriptor.

If I set `keypool: true` as one of the arguments the keys get added to the keypool.

How does the wallet prioritise which keys it generates when calling `getnewaddress`? Will it prioritise the imported addresses or do I have to request the imported address via the `label` argument in `getnewaddress`? What if I don't add a `label` argument to the `importmulti` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee of the order by the API. But its currently FIFO (first in first out).

If the order/remembering is important to you, consider using `fundrawtransaction` with a wallet where you have private keys disabled `createwallet "name" true`.
Just import pubkeys define the change output address in `fundrawtransaction`.